# Dubugging GAC DLL with IIS 5

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, dll, gac, iis-5

I'm trying to debug a DLL in the GAC with VS 2008 / XP / IIS 5 configuration. Tried to copy the DLL in the C:\\assembly\GAC_MSIL but the symbols still doesnt get loeded :-( Also this interesting post about debugging GAC without having to copy the PDB file into the GAC : http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23

But since I run IIS 5, there's no trace of the w3wp.exe (which seems to be only in IIS  6 and newer). Do you know a trick so I can attach to my web page and trace a referenced DLL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, turns out that the solution without copying the .pdb file is working. Only thing is to attach to the "aspnet_wp" process instead of the "w3wp.exe" mentionned in the post.